# Make tsconfig reference all exported variables (for testing mock/spy/stub)

Tags: typescript

I have a file like this:

Foo.tsx:

```
export default function Foo() {
   return 'hi';
}
```

GroupItem.tsx:

```
import Foo from 'Foo.tsx';

export const useGroupIds = () => [];

export default function GroupItem() {
  const groupIds = useGroupIds();
  return <Foo />
}
```

We see in `GroupItem` I reference `useGroupIds`. This is captured by reference. Is it possible to make TypeScript refer to it as `module.useGroupIds`?

I ask this because I am trying to write a test and put a spy on `useGroupIds` but when I do that `spy(module, 'useGroupIds')` the `GroupItem` is not using this spied one as it caught it by reference.

My hope is to get ts to compile the above like this:

```
import Foo from 'Foo.tsx';

export const useGroupIds = () => [];

export default function GroupItem() {
  const groupIds = GroupItemModule.useGroupIds();
  return <FooModule.default />
}
```

So now when I mock like this:

```
import * as FooModule from './Foo';
import * as GroupItemModule from './GroupItem';

jest.spyOn(FooModule, 'default')
jest.spyOn(GroupItemModule, 'useGroupIds')
```

Then the spied functions will be properly called.

Comment: What's `GroupItemModule.useGroupIds` in your implementation? Your using that instead of the local `useGroupIds`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for reply. That is example of what I want TS to transpile too. I want it to call each export in this style. Rather then capture it by context/scope, because this way, even after spy/stub, the usage in `default` export has reference to original (so spied/stubbed never gets called)

Comment: Types of certainly isn't going to synthesize a namespace inside of a module that exports the members of that name space just so you can reference it. It's also a fairly incoherent request given the nature of closures. It wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @AluanHaddad webpack does this with exports. It namespaces it onto the module.

Comment: I know how exports are transpiled by webpack. It's not relevant.